# Unary operator '!' cannot be applied to an operand of type '()'

Tags: swift, unary-operator

> Unary operator '!' cannot be applied to an operand of type '()'

Getting this error on the Swift 2 migration.

```
func saveContext() {

    if let foregroundMO = VPDataManager.sharedInstance.persistentStack.managedObjectContext
    {
        var error:NSError? = nil;

        let managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = foregroundMO
        managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy

        if (managedObjectContext.hasChanges) && !(managedObjectContext.save())
        {
            VPAnalytics.leaveBreadcrumb("AppDelegate saveContext critical error: \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            logError("Unresolved issue: \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

The error happens on `if (managedObjectContext.hasChanges`...

Comment: does `.save()` return a `bool`?

Comment: Note that the extra parenthesis are complicating the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the method [`save`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) has no return value:

```
func save() throws
```

it will throw an error when failed, so you can check if `save` success like this:

```
func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```